# Nav Direction classes are not added to the generator

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

My Android Studio can not add nav Direction classes to the generator, but it adds databinding classes. I even used the rebuild project a few times, but it didn't work.

[Image build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAccN.png)

[Image my plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWebH.png)

My dependencies

```
    def nav_version = "2.4.1"

implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```

My graph

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:name="com.hosein.nzd.mvvm.fragment.HomeFragment"
    android:label="fragment_home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_detailFragment"
        app:destination="@id/detailFragment" />

</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
    android:name="com.hosein.nzd.mvvm.fragment.DetailFragment"
    android:label="fragment_detail"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail" /></navigation>
```

Comment: Are you trying to import `safe args` plugin?

Comment: No ,this plugin added @SamChen